# jQuery causing page re-load on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using this piece of jQuery to show a message to my users on first visit and on click of the 'info' button.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
if(!localStorage.newVisitor) {
    localStorage.newVisitor="true";
    $('#popUp').fadeIn(300);
}

$('#popUp').click(function(){
    $('#popUp').fadeOut(300);
});

$('#info').click(function(){
    $('#popUp').fadeIn(300);
    }
);
});
```

The html is essentially:

```
<div id="popUp">Hello</div>
<a id="info">Info</a>
```

The CSS:

```
#popUp {
    display: none;
}
```

This is all hunky dory in safari, but when I transfer this to the iPhone for testing, every time I tap the 'Info' button, the popup shows, but then the page instatly refreshes so the message is then reset to it's hidden state.

Any Ideas why this is so anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your css actually have the hashtag missing from 'popUp' or is that just a typo?

Comment: Typo on my part, i'll rectify it for clarity! thanks for spotting it @BillyMoat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace you this:

```
<a id="info">Info</a>
```

To this:

```
<span id="info">Info</span>
```

CSS:

```
#info{cursor:pointer;}
```

Because you are targeting the `id` for the click you dont need the `<a>`, as the `<a>` tag has certain behaviors that it wants to do for example jump to a point on a page or move to another page.

Comment: Ya but <a> tag have different styling than span too

Comment: Its jumping because of the `<a>` if you remove it then it will work as expected. You can style a `<span>` to look how ever you want.

Comment: e.preventDefault() will not make jumping to top of page.

Comment: Yip I know that is also another way to do the same thing.

Comment: Swapping the `<a>` for a `<span>` seemed like the neatest way to do this to me, so I marked this as correct, but I also voted @roasted 's answer up as that would work too. Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#info').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#popUp').fadeIn(300);        
});
```

Btw, your `<a>` tag should have an `href` attribute:

```
<a id="info" href="#">Info</a>
```